# How do aerostatic machines work?

Tags: fluid-statics, aerodynamics

so i was wondering how aerostatic machines work? So do they actually use the surrounding air to take off?

And how is aerodynamics the ‘opposite’ to this?

Comment: Does a balloon work in vacuum?

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerostat
"In conventional usage, the term aerostat refers to any aircraft that remains aloft primarily using aerostatic buoyancy." (first sentence in paragraph "Terminology")

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy
"Buoyancy [...] or upthrust, is an upward force exerted by a fluid that opposes the weight of a partially or fully immersed object." (first sentence)

So, yes the surrounding air is used to take off.